# When I run /usr/bin/time my_program, how to kill my_program?

Tags: unix, shell, kill

I want to check how long time my program takes. Then I using "/usr/bin/time my_program". When it takes more than 5 seconds, I want to kill it. I tried "kill -9 TIME_S_PID", time is killed, but my_program is still running. So how to kill my_program?

Sorry, my English is really bad...

Thanks.

Comment: A bit off topic here, but how do you find the PID of time? It doesn't show up with `ps aux | grep time` or in htop/top (running in another terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most unixes have `pkill`, which kills a process based on name
Try: `pkill my_program`

/usr/bin/time my_program
sleep 5
pkill -TERM my_program

Also, don't kill with -9.  It doesn't allow cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

I've never dabbled in unix but can't you just kill "my_program" instead of "time"? I would expect it to have it's own process id.

Comment: Yep, while I've been looking for `time`'s PID, I found killing the process `time` is timing works a treat, and then `time` finishes up with it's summary information.